# How to use pyz file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyz

There is a pyz file that has all the dependency bundle I need (numpy, tensorflow....etc)

I am wondering how do I run a function inside that pyz file.

For example if there is a function called `runJob`

I would like to call that function in my script

```
import function_from_pyz
if __name__ == "__main__":
    funciton_from_pyz.runJob()
```

The following doesn't quite work

```
<python path> my_pyz_file.pyz myscript.py
```

Answer (score 0):

A .pyz file is just a normal zip with a header that allows it to be executed.  Python can import modules from a zip file exactly like from a subdirectory.

So, if the function is in a file called `__main__.py`, you just do:

```
from my_pyz_file.__main__ import runJob
```